# Blender -Bones rotating arround origin when exported animation

Tags: animation

I have a problem:
I can record skeletal animations normally using blender.
However when I export the collada file, I see that all my rotations are now performed arround the origing, and no longer arroud each bone own's axis.
So as a result, the animations are all wrong.
How to I keep the correct rotations when exporting a collada file.

Comment: Did you try it import back to Blender, just make sure the problem is not in the game engine?

Comment: yes, I've tried that. and the bug is also presented in blender

Comment: Here is the original FBX file https://youtu.be/sWZbDYoCBdE and this is the collada exported file : https://youtu.be/ztZSP9rWaAs

Comment: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/super-mario-odyssey-mario-high-poly-cf20ee18811e498c85da56b1fea0c94e this is the file itself. I'm using int in a non commercial academic project.